# How to count entries in updated listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, listbox

I have a Windows Form which contains a listbox (`Listbox1`), a label (`label1`) and a button (`button1`). I have assigned a click event to `button1` and the code is as follows:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                  
    label1.Text = "Parsing entries && initializing comms ...";

    apples = new Task(Apple);
    apples.Start();
    Task.WaitAll(apples);

    label1.Text = "No. of items: " + Listbox1.Items.Count.ToString();

    if (Listbox1.Items.Count >= 2)
    {
        Listbox1.SetSelected(1, true);
    }
}

public void Apple() {    
//Send 1st command - 90000
command = "90000";
CommPort com = CommPort.Instance;

if (command.Length > 0)
{
command = ConvertEscapeSequences(command);
com.Send(command);
}
Thread.Sleep(100); //allow 100ms delay for receiving response from serial port

//Send 2nd command - 90001
command = "90001";

if (command.Length > 0)
{
command = ConvertEscapeSequences(command);
com.Send(command);
}
Thread.Sleep(100); //allow 100ms delay for receiving response from serial port

//Send 3rd command - 90002
command = "90002";

if (command.Length > 0)
{
command = ConvertEscapeSequences(command);
com.Send(command);
}
Thread.Sleep(100); //allow 100ms delay for receiving response from serial port

//Send 4th command - 90003
command = "90003";

if (command.Length > 0)
{
command = ConvertEscapeSequences(command);
com.Send(command);
}
Thread.Sleep(100); //allow 100ms delay for receiving response from serial port

//Send 5th command - 90004
command = "90004";

if (command.Length > 0)
{
command = ConvertEscapeSequences(command);
com.Send(command);
}
Thread.Sleep(100); //allow 100ms delay for receiving response from serial port

//Send 6th command - 90005
command = "90005";

if (command.Length > 0)
{
command = ConvertEscapeSequences(command);
com.Send(command);
}
Thread.Sleep(100); //allow 100ms delay for receiving response from serial port
//Listbox1 eventually contains some (~6) entries
}
```

However, when I click on `button1`, `label1` displays the text `No. of items: 0`, although `Listbox1` does in fact contain 6 items. Why is it that the code `Listbox1.Items.Count.ToString()` returns 0 when there are actually 6 items in `Listbox1`?

Comment: Does your application freeze or is it still responsive? You shouldn't use blocking calls on the UI thread such as `WaitAll` as this can cause a deadlock.

Comment: Ned's comment is correct in that you should not be blocking with `Task.WaitAll( )` on the UI thread. But that issue aside, your code supplied does not explain the count mismatch: `(Listbox1.Items.Count).ToString()` is correct and should display the number of items currently in `Listbox1`. Something else must be going on.

Comment: @Special Sauce, I agree. I was just trying to find out more information about the behavior of the program. I suspect we need to know what happens inside `Apple()`

Comment: @Shiraz S Kaderuppan, can you post the code for the `Apple` method?

Comment: NedStoyanov & Special Sauce, thanks for your prompt replies. It seems that the application momentarily freezes, but when I click on button1 again, the correct entry in `Listbox1` is now selected, although Listbox1 now contains 12 items (instead of 6). I shall post the `Apple` method in about a couple of hours, if the problem is still not resolved.

Comment: @NedStoyanov: Now, this is strange - shortly after I posted this, the thread now seems to lock up (& the application freezes) at the line `Parsing entries && initializing comms ...`. Ned, what other method do you suggest would be better than `Task.WaitAll()` in this instance, since I really need to return the output from the `Appples` method into Listbox1, before proceeding to select the 2nd entry from Listbox1? I thought that async would be the best option in this instance, hence my use of `Task.WaitAll()`.

Comment: The `Apples` method is indicated in my post above. It communicates with a serial device which returns a response to the serial command entered (e.g. `90000`) and this response is stored as an entry in Listbox1.

Comment: Sorry for the previous typos - the method name should read `Apple`, not `Apples` (& definitely not `Appples` ... :p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use blocking calls on the UI thread such as `WaitAll` as this can cause a deadlock, a better alternative is to use `async-await`.

There is a good article on best practices for async-await [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

You can only use `await` inside an `async` mehtod, so you will need to make `button1_Click` `async` and then `await` the call to `Apple`.

The method that you `await` will need to return a `Task` or `Task<T>` so `Apple`'s return value will need to be changed to one of those. You can send any synchronous blocking calls to the thread pool with `Task.Run` however any GUI elements must be accessed on the main thread outside of the `Task.Run` delegate which will run on the thread pool.

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                  
   label1.Text = "Parsing entries && initializing comms ...";
   await Apple();

   label1.Text = "No. of items: " + ((Listbox1.Items.Count).ToString());

   if (Listbox1.Items.Count >= 2)
   {
      Listbox1.SetSelected(1, true);
   }
}

public async Task Apple() 
{
   await Task.Run(()=>
        {
           // serial comms work ...              
        }

   // add items to list here ...
}
```

If your serial comms api supprts `async`, i.e. `SendAsync`, you can just `await` the `SendAsync` calls and use `await Task.Delay(100)` to do asynchronous sleep, you don't need `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly [with the exception of a missing `);` & when coupled with appropriate `await Apple.Delay(..)` commands]. :)